# Clustering with imbalanced data and groups

Tags: clustering, imbalance

I have a problem that is about identifying clusters of highly correlated items. I initially focused on building a model and features that put similar data items close to each other. The main challenge is that I have a case of imbalanced data, as follows:

- Tens of Millions of items are random and not necessarily correlated.
- Hundreds of clusters of items (composed of 10-1000s of elements) exist* or may emerge. *I do have partial ground truth for the existing ones.
- Clusters are very different, in size and properties.

I'd like to return the *identified clusters*, and the *elements within each cluster*. F1 should be a good measure.

To move forward, I can think of threshold-based hierarchical clustering. Are there other techniques to consider?

Comment: Are you thinking along the lines of DBSCAN, OPTICS, BIRCH?

Comment: Thanks! Would these work efficiently in the imbalanced case? @Vlad_Z

Comment: DBSCAN works well on imbalanced data in my experience

Comment: If you're measuring F1, I'm assuming you have some ground truth for each of the clusters. In which case, you might look at a nearest neighbor classifier where the ground truth is used as a label... or some variant of nn that works well on imbalanced data.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I have the ground truth for some clusters. but new ones can emerge.

Answer (score 1):

As you have the partial ground-truth (assuming for ALL clusters) I would suggest following a creative idea derived from [Region Growing in image segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing).

As your clusters are imbalanced in number of the points thus density, they are probably captured by localy using DBSCAN. Run DBSCAN with different parameters and evaluate on capturing your ground-truth into right clusters. The partitioning which gives the best result on your ground-truth evaluation will be your final clustering.